# How can I update the value of a column for two rows that have a unique constraint in SQLite?

Tags: update, sqlite, unique-constraint

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS node (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  type TEXT CHECK(type IN ("DIRECTORY", "EXECUTABLE", "DOCUMENT")) NOT NULL,
  siblingOrder INTEGER NOT NULL,
  parentId INTEGER,
  UNIQUE (parentId, siblingOrder) ON CONFLICT ABORT,
  FOREIGN KEY(parentId) REFERENCES node(id)
);
```

No two rows should have the same `parentId` and `siblingOrder`.

I am inserting the following data

```
INSERT INTO node (id, name, type, siblingOrder, parentId) 
VALUES 
(1, "", "DIRECTORY", 0, null),
(2, "Users", "DIRECTORY", 0, 1),
(3, "sys", "DIRECTORY", 1, 1),
(4, "bin", "DIRECTORY", 2, 1),
(5, "Desktop", "DIRECTORY", 0, 2),
(6, "New Folder", "DIRECTORY", 0, 5),
(7, "config", "DOCUMENT", 0, 3),
(8, "README", "DOCUMENT", 1, 5),
(9, "resume", "DOCUMENT", 2, 5),
(10, "Terminal", "EXECUTABLE", 3, 5);
```

Now, I would like to swap the `siblingOrder` of, for example, rows with the id of `8` and `9`.

If I try this,

```
UPDATE node 
    SET siblingOrder = CASE id 
        WHEN 8 THEN 2
        WHEN 9 THEN 1
    END
WHERE id IN (8, 9);
```

it of course fails, because ( I think ) it is attempting to set the `siblingOrder` of row with `id=8` to `2` while row of `id=9` still has a `siblingOrder` of `2` while they share the same `parentId`.

How can I swap the `siblingOrder` of these two rows while still maintaining the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: After posting this question, I have come across this answer which appears relevant 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798272/updating-database-records-with-unique-constraint

but I am not sure if it solves my case yet.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798420/15753188

the following has worked for me

```
UPDATE node 
    SET siblingOrder = CASE id 
        WHEN 8 THEN -2
        WHEN 9 THEN -1
    END
WHERE id IN (8, 9);

UPDATE node
    SET siblingOrder = CASE id
        WHEN 8 THEN 2
        WHEN 9 THEN 1
    END
WHERE id IN (8, 9);
```